# How to integrate a COM object in Dynamics Ax 2009 on server side?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a .NET 4.0 dll that I would like to integrate to Dynamics Ax 2009 on server side. In client side (RunOn: client), it works fine with a 32 bit dll. But on server side (RunOn:server), it doesn't work.

Here is what I do:
(1) I copy an instance of the 64 bit dll to the bin folder of the AOS, and
(2) I add the the necessary entries to the registry with Regasm.exe.

After  I use the following code:

```
server static void ComIntegrationTest(Args _args)
{
    COM com;
    ;
    new InteropPermission(InteropKind::ComInterop).assert();
    com = new COM('{A2686EE2-8382-3D04-B908-31AF4E5AF5B5}');
    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
}
```

I receive the following error message:
COM object of class '{A2686EE2-8382-3D04-B908-31AF4E5AF5B5}' could not be created. Ensure that the object has been properly registered on computer 'MSS2008R2-AXAOS'.
Object 'COM' could not be created

Or if I wrap the COM object in a x++ class with Com class wrapper wizard, and try to make an instance of the wrapper class, I receive  following error message:
Request for the permission of type 'InteropPermission' failed.
Object 'COM' could not be created.

**EDIT:**

If it is not possible to do it, how can I integrate Dynamics Ax 2009 with .NET 4.0?

It is not possible to directly reference a .NET 4.0 dll that is in the GAC, because Dynamics Ax 2009 is only compatibly with .NET 3.5 or previous versions of .NET.

Comment: I'm surprised that I haven't seen this question before for AX2009.  Below is a link how to make the COM object but from reading the above it appears that you have already taken all of the correct steps.
http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/arik/2011/05/30/how-to-use-a-net-4-based-dll-from-net-2-based-application/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are mixing .Net and COM integration, they live on different planets.

You should [strongly sign](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41(v=vs.100).aspx) your .Net assembly, then [register in GAC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79(v=vs.100).aspx).

See also [this problem](https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/33/t/94387.aspx) and [this description part 1](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/working-microsoft-dynamics-ax-and-net-part-1) and [part 2](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/working-microsoft-dynamics-ax-and-net-part-2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In Dynamics Ax 2009, It is only possible to use signed .NET 3.5 dlls as clr objects that are registered in the GAC. I have a 3rd party dll that uses .NET 4.0., therefore I cannot do it. Therefore I am trying a COM integration. It works fine in Axapta 3.0.

Comment: When I say COM integration, I mean that I use the following command to register the .NET dll to the registry: regasm /tlb:MyWrapper "MyWrapper.dll". And then I reference it from Dynamics Ax:  Com com = new COM('{A2686EE2-8382-3D04-B908-31AF4E5AF5B5}').

Comment: Do not use `new COM` to reference .Net assemblies.

Comment: It works on client side in this way (with COM). But I cannot reference it as clr object, if it is in the GAC, because it uses .NET 4.0, and Dynamics Ax 2009 is not compatible with .NET 4.